# bash script : test for video files failed

Tags: bash

I have written a little bash script to extract audio from video files in batch mode.

Sound is extracted from each mp4 file to flac format using avconv (and the flac codec).

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Batch conversion of audio extraction from video

FOLDER_SRC="/home/Me/Music/TestBatchConv"

for myvid in $(find ${FOLDER_SRC} | grep mp4)
do
avconv -i $myvid -acodec flac "${myvid}.flac"
done

exit 0
```

It works fine, but I would like to improve it.

How do I test if the file is a video ?
I tried something like

```
for myvid in $(find ${FOLDER_SRC})
do
    if [ file -i $myvid | grep video ]
        then avconv -i $myvid -acodec flac "${myvid}.flac"
    fi
done
```

but i cant get it done (yes i am new to this).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rewrite your new test as

```
 if  file -i $myvid | grep -q video  ; then
```

The -q option means quiet, so grep returns `true` if it finds the search target and `false` if not. The `if` responds appropriately depending on the `true` or `false` state that is returned.

Braces used with `if` statements are really an alias tot the `test` cmd, so something like

```
  if [ $(file -i $myvid | grep video) = "video" ] ; then
```

would also work.

To learn how to get this sort of thing right, just work on the command line, and add one bit at a time, i.e.

```
 file -i $myvid
```

then

```
file -i $myvid | grep video
```

OR

```
file -i $myvid | grep -q video ; echo $?
```

And to see the inverse, change to

```
file -i $myvid | grep nonesuch ; echo $?
```

**EDIT**

And to test for more than one thing, you can use `egrep`, i.e.

```
 if  file -i $myvid | egrep -q 'video|application/octet'  ; then
```

IHTH

Comment: The `grep` coding style leads to awful slow scripts. It should be avoided as much as possible. Better is to do use the `output=$(cmd); if [[ ${output} ~= regExp ]]` pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works fine with `if file -i $myvid | grep -q video ;` I have just noticed that the test doesn't work with mkv files, because file -i *.mkv returns application/octet and not video.

Answer (score 2):

#### I would first create a file list

```
   find ${FOLDER_SRC} -type f -exec file \{\} +
```

Only one invocation of `file`, see `man find` and look for "-exec command {} +"

#### Add a simple workaround for spaces

```
   find ${FOLDER_SRC} -type f -exec file \{\} + |tr ' ' '°'
```

Simple and sufficient.
An alternative is the use of `mapfile`.

#### Iterate over the file list and define actions in a case statement

```
   for line in $(find ${FOLDER_SRC} -type f -exec file \{\} + |tr ' ' '°')
   do
     file=${line%%:*}
     file=${file//°/ }          
     content=${line#*:}
     content=${content//°/ }          
     case "${content}" in
         *video/mp2p*) myConvertFunctionA;;
         *video/mpeg*) myConvertFunctionB;;
         *video*) echo "found unsupported video type: ${content}";;
     esac
   done
```

- string manipulations via bash builtins are fast
- `case` is easy to understand
- avoid multiple instantion of `grep`

Comment: Thx, your solution answers to another question I had (to write info in file), and may be more universal (since the mkv format is not recognized as a video with `file -i *.mkv`, but as application/octet).

Answer (score 1):

The use of 'file' works against magic numbers, so it can be wrong sometimes.

I've used 'mplayer' to grab the data:

```
mplayer -ao null -vo null -endpos 0.01 ${MEDIAFILE} 2>/dev/null | egrep "AUDIO:|VIDEO:"
```

This will give matches against audio and video. You can omit one or the other or add a '-c' to the egrep so you can do a match:

```
if [ `mplayer -ao null -vo null -endpos 0.01 ${MEDIAFILE} | egrep -c "VIDEO:"` -gt 0 ]; then
    # HANDLE VIDEO FILE
fi
```

However, since you are extracting audio from video files, you'd probably want to make sure that a video file you want to process also has an audio component:

```
AVCHECK=`mplayer -ao null -vo null -endpos 0.01 ${MEDIAFILE} 2>/dev/null | egrep "AUDIO:|VIDEO:"`

if [ `echo "${AVCHECK}" | grep -c AUDIO` && `echo "${AVCHECK}" | grep -c VIDEO` ]; then
    # STRIP AUDIO FROM VIDEO FILE
fi
```